# Media player stop() method not working in samsung phone

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i have implement Media player funtionality in my sound app.

It works fine in all devices instead of samsung phone.When i clicked on stop button, player continously playing the sound.Here is my stop button code.

```
if (mState.equals(State.Playing)) {
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    mState = State.Paused;
                    if (mState == State.Playing)
                        mContentView
                                .setImageViewResource(R.id.playPauseButton,
                                        R.drawable.pause_icon);
                    else
                        mContentView.setImageViewResource(
                                R.id.playPauseButton, R.drawable.play_icon);
                    mBuilder.setContent(mContentView);

                    mNotification = mBuilder.build();
                    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,
                            mNotification);}
```